# JQuery Sync Selected Radio Button between 2 radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it can be done with input boxes using keyup paste on JQuery but what about Radio buttons?

Example:

User Selects option from Area A (radio button) and it selects(syncs) area B

```
<!--AREA A (Source) -->
<input id="radio_A" name="radio_A" type="radio" value="Value1" />
<input id="radio_A2" name="radio_A" type="radio" value="Value2" />

<!--AREA B (Target)-->

<input id="radio_B" name="radio_B" type="radio" value="Value1" />
<input id="radio_B2" name="radio_B" type="radio" value="Value2" />
```

Comment: "_JQuery Sync Selected Radio Button between 2_" I don't understand the topic

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#radio_A").click(function() {
    $("#radio_B").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
});
$("#radio_A2").click(function() {
    $("#radio_B2").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nFbfz/)**

Comment: keyboard input won't fire a click event, better to use .change()

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name=radio_A]').change(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_A]');
    $('input[name=radio_B]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/BUbHf/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[name='radioGroup1'][value='"+$("input[name='radioGroup2']:checked").val()+"']").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer