# Sync Selected Radio Button between 2 radio button groups - Opposites

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I need to do something similar to [JQuery Sync Selected Radio Button between 2 radio button groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804377/jquery-sync-selected-radio-button-between-2-radio-button-groups).

I have 2 radio groups -

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_A" id="radio_A_1" value="1" />1st
<input type="radio" name="radio_A" id="radio_A_2" value="2" />2nd 

<input type="radio" name="radio_B" id="radio_B_1" value="1" />1st
<input type="radio" name="radio_B" id="radio_B_2" value="2" />2nd
```

When `radio_A_1` is checked, I need `radio_B_2` synced/checked. The relationships would be-
`radio_A_1`=>`radio_B_2`
`radio_A_2`=>`radio_B_1`
`radio_B_1`=>`radio_A_2`
`radio_B_2`=>`radio_A_1`

Using the answer provided [#8804502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804377/jquery-sync-selected-radio-button-between-2-radio-button-groups#8804502)

```
$('input[name=radio_A]').change(function() {
var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_A]');
console.log(index);
$('input[name=radio_B]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

I get same=>same, but only when `A` changes-
`radio_A_1`=>`radio_B_1`
`radio_A_2`=>`radio_B_2`

So if I copy it, changing it if from `A=>B` to `B=>A`-

```
$('input[name=radio_A]').change(function() {
var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_A]');
console.log(index);
$('input[name=radio_B]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked','checked');
});
$('input[name=radio_B]').change(function() {
var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_B]');
console.log(index);
$('input[name=radio_A]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

I get same=>same, when either `A` or `B` changes -
`radio_A_1`=>`radio_B_1`
`radio_A_2`=>`radio_B_2`
`radio_B_1`=>`radio_A_1`
`radio_B_2`=>`radio_A_2`

How can I sync them `1=>2`/`2=>1`, instead of `1=>1`/`2=>2`? And can it be done with 1 block of code, instead of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some code to take the `index` of the element just clicked and set it to `0` if it is `1`, or `1` if it is `0`. The first way that came to mind is as follows:

```
$('input[name=radio_A]').change(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_A]') === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    $('input[name=radio_B]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
$('input[name=radio_B]').change(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('input[name=radio_B]') === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    $('input[name=radio_A]:eq(' + index + ')').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cTQeJ/1/

Though you could also try:

```
var index = 1 - $(this).index('input[name=radio_A]');
```

(Or the following demo uses kind of a fun hack if you like to make your code confusing: http://jsfiddle.net/cTQeJ/)

> *"And can it be done with 1 block of code, instead of 2?"*

If you can modify the html slightly it is pretty easy with a single, short code block. Try a change like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_A" data-sync="1" value="1" />1st
<input type="radio" name="radio_A" data-sync="2" value="2" />2nd

<input type="radio" name="radio_B" data-sync="2" value="1" />1st
<input type="radio" name="radio_B" data-sync="1" value="2" />2nd
```

I've added a `data-sync` attribute to each radio button (and removed the `id` attribute since it wasn't being used, but obviously you can leave that in if needed). Then you can write a simple function like this:

```
var $radios = $('input[data-sync]');
$radios.change(function() {
    $radios.filter('[data-sync="' + $(this).attr('data-sync') + '"]')
           .prop('checked', true);
});​
```

...that basically says whenever any of the radio buttons is checked, find all other radio buttons with a `data-sync` attribute of the same value and check them too.

Note that this will work with more than two groups, as shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cTQeJ/2/

Comment: This works great. Thank you for your help. I especially like the line 'the following demo uses kind of a fun hack'.